# Finding exon/ intron borders in a gene

Tags: python, biopython

I would like to go through a gene and get a list of 10bp long sequences containing the exon/intron borders  from each `feature.type =='mRNA'`. It seems like I need to use `compoundLocation`, and the locations used in `'join'` but I can not figure out how to do it, or find a tutorial.

Could anyone please give me an example or point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Is the gene in GenBank format with the intron/exon boundaries indicated in the annotations, or are you trying to identify boundaries by sequence analysis?

Comment: The gene is in GenBank format.  I am trying to find out how to go through the "join{[0:229](+), [11680:11768](+), [11871:12135](+), [15277:15339](+), [16136:16416](+), [17220:17471](+), [17547:17671](+)"  Ideally I would like to get each position +/ 20bp on each side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the info in the exact format you show in the comment, and that you're looking for 20 bp on either side of each intro/exon boundary, something like this might be a start:

***Edit:*** If you're actually starting from a GenBank record, then it's not much harder.  Assuming that the full junction string you're looking for is in the CDS feature info, then:

```
for f in record.features:
    if f.type == 'CDS':
        jct_info = str(f.location)
```

converts the "location" information into a string and you can continue as below.

(There are ways to work directly with the location information without converting to a string - in particular you can use "extract" to pull the spliced sequence directly out of the parent sequence -- but the steps involved in what you want to do are faster and more easily done by converting to str and then int.)

```
import re
jct_info = "join{[0:229](+), [11680:11768](+), [11871:12135](+), [15277:15339](+), [16136:16416](+), [17220:17471](+), [17547:17671](+)"
jctP = re.compile("\[\d+\:\d+\]")   
jcts = jctP.findall(jct_info)

jcts
['[0:229]', '[11680:11768]', '[11871:12135]', '[15277:15339]', '[16136:16416]', '[17220:17471]', '[17547:17671]']
```

Now you can loop through the list of start:end values, pull them out of the text and convert them to ints so that you can use them as sequence indexes.  Something like this:

```
for jct in jcts:
    (start,end) = jct.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(':')
    try:   # You need to account for going out of index, e.g. where start = 0
        start_20_20 = seq[int(start)-20:int(start)+20]
    except IndexError:
        # do your alternatives e.g. start = int(start)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the "join{[0:229](+)..." is not a string.  It is a "location_operator".  If I set a variable equal to it, then loop through the variable, it displays "join...", then afterwards, all of the numbers it joined together.  This might be something specific for biopython, and I may have jumped in a little too deep...

Comment: Actually just the "join" part is a location_operator; the string you're interested in is a "location", and you can easily convert it to a string with str(location), then continue.

Comment: You are right, it works great!  A nice simple solution.  I did not consider converting the whole thing into a string and moving on from there.  I was trying to go about it using Biopython.  Thanks!